# Delete an entire data.table by reference

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

Is it possible to delete a `data.table` object by reference? How could a function `rm_tbl()` be implemented that takes a `data.table` object and assigns `NULL` to any name pointing to this object in any environment (that is a descendant of the globalenv)?

Examples, which for obvious reasons do not work, but perhaps convey the idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
rm_tbl_1 <- function(tbl) {
  rm(tbl)
  invisible(NULL)
}

rm_tbl_2 <- function(tbl) {
  tbl <<- NULL
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

The following comes close, but is a bit of a hack (also it does not result in `NULL` but a zero-row `data.table`)

```
rm_tbl_3 <- function(tbl) {
  tbl[, colnames(tbl) := rep(list(NULL), ncol(tbl))]
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

For completeness:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)

rm_tbl_1(dt)
dt
rm_tbl_2(dt)
dt
rm_tbl_3(dt)
dt
```

### Edit

As per upvoted suggestion by @Gregor, some further explanation: The problem I'm facing is that I have a large `data.table`. Now somewhere in a function, I do something to this object, e.g. call `data.table::split()` and I no longer have any need for the original `data.table`. Additionally, In order to do further transformations on my data, I need the memory back of the original `data.table`. How do I do that?

An example:

```
fun_a <- function() {
  dt <- data.table(a = 1:2, b = 2:3)
  fun_b(dt)
}

fun_b <- function(tbl) {
  temp <- split(tbl, by = "b")
  rm_dt(tbl)
  do_stuff_with_dt(temp)
}

fun_a()
```

Does this clear things up? I'm sorry for not being clearer to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
rm_dt <- function(name) {
  # Get data.table of all data.tables in global environment
  tbls <- tables(env=.GlobalEnv, silent=TRUE)
  # Look up the externalptr address for each data.table
  tbls <- tbls[, .(addr=eval(parse(text=sprintf("data.table::address(%s)", NAME)))), 
                 by = NAME]
  # Find all data.tables that have the same externalptr address as the one requested for deletion
  to_rm <- tbls[addr == tbls[NAME == name, addr], NAME]
  # Delete them
  rm(list=to_rm, pos=".GlobalEnv")
}

dt <- data.table(a=1)
dt2 <- dt
dt3 <- data.table(a=1)

rm_dt("dt") # should delete dt and dt2, but not dt3
```

Note this will only delete all references in the global environment, if you create a reference in another environment this won't be deleted:

```
dt <- data.table(a=1)
dt2 <- dt
e <- new.env()
e$dt3 <- dt

# dt and dt2 will be removed, but e$dt3 will still exist
rm_dt("dt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately this is not quite what I was looking for, as for this to work, I have to know exactly in which envs all these references are located. I guess what I am looking for does not exists (as per [#3127](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3127)). Didn't know about `data.table::tables()`, though, so thanks for that!

Comment: I suspect it may not even be possible - I don't know that there is a mechanism to keep track of what variables are associated with each `externalptr`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
rm_tbl_4 <- function(tbl) {
  tbl = deparse(substitute(tbl))
  rm(list = tbl, pos = ".GlobalEnv")
}

dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
rm_tbl_4(dt)
dt
```

You could also include the environment as function variable, so you can decide where to delete it from.

```
rm_tbl_4 <- function(tbl, env) {
  tbl = deparse(substitute(tbl))
  rm(list = tbl, pos = env)
}

dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
rm_tbl_4(dt, env=".GlobalEnv")
dt
```

Comment: This does not, however work in the case where I have multiple names pointing to the same `data.table`, right? I was more hoping for something that somehow triggers finalization of the `externalptr`, or the like.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly..Why would you have multiple names of the same table? And what should get deleted in that case?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. What I want is to free the memory occupied by the data of some `data.table` object. I would assume that if this object was no longer bound to any name, it then gets `gc`ed and finalization of the `externalptr` is triggered. What `rm_tbl_4` does is looking up the name of the `tbl` argument in the calling env and then removing the corresponding object. But what if you consider a further level on nesting: a function calls a function calls `rm_tbl` and in the outermost scope, the `data.table` is bound to yet another name. In this scenario, your suggestion fails, no?

Comment: Could you include an example of what you mean and your desired behaviour? I still dont get the idea I think. Objects defined inside a function will be in function scope and wont be stored in the global environment.

Comment: For an example where your approach fails, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/nbenn/86e6585e3014f127d6c5cb30c83d2a96). Even if you'd walk all calling env's you would not catch all references to `dt`, as they are bound to different names. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes in this case, it will fail as it will look for an object named "data_table", which wont be found. You wou'd have to put the `deparse(substitute())` in the outer-most function. In your case in function `fun_a`. I'll add a comment to your gist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182503/discussion-between-nbenn-and-sega).

Comment: @nbenn I'd strongly recommend editing your question to show an example of what you mean, rather than just linking to a gist buried in the comments of an answer.